# I am having issues compiling my code with this error prompting after compilation

Tags: javascript, reactjs

ERROR in ./src/App.js 30:41-47

> export 'Switch' (imported as 'Switch') was not found in
> 'react-router-dom' (possible exports: BrowserRouter, HashRouter, Link,
> MemoryRouter, NavLink, Navigate, Outlet, Route, Router, Routes,
> UNSAFE_LocationContext, UNSAFE_NavigationContext, UNSAFE_RouteContext,
> createRoutesFromChildren, createSearchParams, generatePath, matchPath,
> matchRoutes, renderMatches, resolvePath, unstable_HistoryRouter,
> useHref, useInRouterContext, useLinkClickHandler, useLocation,
> useMatch, useNavigate, useNavigationType, useOutlet, useOutletContext,
> useParams, useResolvedPath, useRoutes, useSearchParams

Answer (score 2):

In react-router-dom v6, "Switch" is replaced by routes "Routes". You need to update the import from

```js
import { Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
```

to

```js
import { Routes ,Route } from 'react-router-dom';
```

For more information, you can visit offical docs: [react-router-dom-v6](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/overview)

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1:**

To Solve 'Switch' is not exported from 'react-router-dom' Error Here Just Install Switch. And then you can use Switch. Switch is replaced in react-router-dom version 6. So that you need to install react-router-dom version 5. Now, your error should be solved.

Use routes instead of Switch:

```js
import {
  BrowserRouter,
  Routes, // Just Use Routes instead of "Switch"
  Route,
} from "react-router-dom";
```

Then You can use Like This:

```js
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route exact path="/" element={<Home />}>
          <Home/>
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
```

**Solution 2:**

Here Just Install Switch. And then you can use Switch. Switch is replaced in react-router-dom version 6. So that you need to install react-router-dom version 5. Now, your error should be solved.

```js
npm install react-router-dom@5
```

Thanks